# How can I include other files in log4j2 yaml configuration?

Tags: configuration, yaml, include, log4j2

I have a problem in log4j2 with yaml configuration.

When I write a configuration with xml, I use "xi:include" tag to include another xml file.
(https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#xinclude)

But I can't find the way to include another yml file in yaml configuration.

I tried to use "Include" key, but I got an error message. (main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for Include)

Is there a way to include another yml file in log4j2?

Thanks.